# Can Endeca Integrator Studio export a script to perform ETL on a RHEL server without a GUI?

Tags: oracle, integration, etl, clover, endeca

We are using a **Java Endeca API** to perform ETL on various datasources on our production servers. It appears that **Oracle Endeca Integrator Studio** (**Clover ETL**) has the ability to perform many of these tasks. But it would not be possible to run **Endeca Integrator Studio** on production servers which lack GUI features. Is there a way to have Integrator export scripts that could be run in command mode on a Linux server?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Oracle Endeca Integrator Server product.  It is a long-running, headless service with a web management interface.  You can then execute Integrator projects and ETL graphs on the remote server, or schedule them to run periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Endeca 3.0 has Integrator web Administration console as well but I am not sure to what extent it would be useful to you.